# Layouts within Layouts in Kivy with Python

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I want to make a layout within a layout using the `Kivy` library in Python instead of using the Kivy language builder as shown below:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<ListScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: .1
                Button:
                    text: 'Save'
                Button:
                    text: 'Load'
                Button:
                    text: 'New'
                Button:
                    text: 'New'
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                        root.manager.current = 'search'
""")
```

I am having difficulty figuring out how to access the second layout to add widgets to it. Sample code below:

```
class ListScreen(Screen):
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
    layout.add_widget(top_buttons=BoxLayout())
    top_buttons.add_widget(save=Button(text='Save')
    # ^ problem here, it won't recognize top_buttons
```

As you can see, I tried to access top_buttons outside of the layout, but I can't figure out how to reach it, so I cannot add my widgets to it. How should I access it to add widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ListScreen(Screen):

    layout = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
    layout.add_widget(top_buttons=BoxLayout()) # <--------
    top_buttons.add_widget(save=Button(text='Save')
```

Exactly because of that line you can't use the variable `top_buttons`, because you used that as a *keyword*, not a variable. It should look like this:

```
class ListScreen(Screen):

    layout = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
    top_buttons=BoxLayout()
    layout.add_widget(top_buttons) # <--------
    top_buttons.add_widget(save=Button(text='Save')
```